# Unable to transact Operator.setAuthorizedSenders on Chainlink - Goerli

Tags: blockchain, chainlink, chainlink-keepers

Completed the local node setup on ubuntu 20.04, and the chainlink node is up and running.
Deployed the Operator.sol, while executing the 'setAuthorizedSenders' method from remix getting following error:

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
> execution reverted: Cannot set authorized senders
> {
> "originalError": {
> "code": 3,
> "data": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d43616e6e6f742073657420617574686f72697a65642073656e64657273000000",
> "message": "execution reverted: Cannot set authorized senders"
> }
> }

Answer (score 0):

It is my mistake. Sent the node address as the admin address for owner during the contract deployment. It is working as expected.